# How do I show that an endomorphism is self-adjoint if and only if $\langle u, Tu \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $u \in \mathbb{V}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, abstract-algebra

Let $$(V,\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle)$$ be a complex vector space. 
Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ be an endomorphism.

Now I want to show, that $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is self-adjoint if and only if $$\langle u, Tu \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$$ for all $u \in V$.

Now I have to show both directions.

1) $\langle u,Tu \rangle = \langle Tu , u \rangle  = \overline{ \langle u,Tu \rangle}$ and therefore $\langle u,Tu \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$

Is this right? And how can I show the other direction?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of space your workning in and what your definition of self adjoint is but you can look at
$$(x+iy,T(x+iy)) \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Is is a complex  vector space I'm working with

Comment: and $(x,y)=\overline{(y,x)}$ ? Then my suggestion should work.